# PHP undefined index but defined earlier on

Tags: php, html, web

I am making a script which is going to add together a bunch of inputs. I am almost there, but when testing the script i seem to get the alert: Notice: Undefined index: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\Archers.php on line 25. Even though I have declared it earlier and even when using it now. The script is below. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    Enter how many values you would like to enter:
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
  <?php
  $number = 0;
  $result = 0;
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $x = 0;
    echo "<form method=\"post\">";
    while ($x != $number) {
      echo "Enter score: <input type=\"text\" name=\"".'a'.$x."\"><br>";
      $x = $x + 1;
    }
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit2\"></form>";
  }
  if (isset($_POST["submit2"])){
    $y = 0;
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    while ($y != $number){
      $value = $_POST["a".$y];
      $result = $result + $value;
      $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo $result;
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is not on about `$number` its on about `$_POST['number']` the second form is sending `a123` not `number`

Comment: it's because `$_POST['number']` isnt defined in the second form submit2, you should either use a global variable `number` or include the first input in the second form

Comment: Also enter `100000000000000` and see what happens.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone obviously BO without even trying it

Answer (score 0):

The error you received is because the index of array is undefined - it simply does not exist. That's probably `$number = $_POST['number']` line in your code (25th).

It surely means that you did not fill number input in your form, as you have no validation to a possibility that number field is not passed.

EDIT: I can see that you have created second form, which has `submit2` key in it. When you POST for the first time, you will receive both `submit` and `number` keys (in lines 14 - 22). Then your code creates second form, which makes another POST with `submit2` but without `number` field in it. Therefore, you don't have `number` key in lines 23 - 32.

EDIT2:
You can, for example, change the first if to be like this one:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $x = 0;
    echo "<form method=\"post\">";
    while ($x != $number) {
        echo "Enter score: <input type=\"text\" name=\"".'a'.$x."\"><br>";
        $x = $x + 1;
    }
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"number\" value=\"" . $number . "\">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit2\"></form>";
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have removed the second line of getting the post. But i still can't get the variable to transfer across from the first isset...

Comment: @Blatherwick See the second edit.

Comment: nvm I fixed it using sessions. each form refreshed the page causinog the variables to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code . it will remove your error

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post">
        Enter how many values you would like to enter:
        <input type="number" name="number">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>
      <?php
      $number = 0;
      $result = 0;
      if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset( $_POST['number']) ){
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $x = 0;
        echo "<form method=\"post\">";
        while ($x != $number) {
          echo "Enter score: <input type=\"text\" name=\"".'a'.$x."\"><br>";
          $x = $x + 1;
        }
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit2\"></form>";
      }
      if (isset($_POST["submit2"]) && isset( $_POST['number'])){
        $y = 0;

        $number = $_POST['number'];

        while ($y != $number){
          $value = $_POST["a".$y];
          $result = $result + $value;
          $y = $y + 1;

        echo $result;
          }
      }
      ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```